# Apple push notifications: Message in twice in Payload

Tags: iphone, apple-push-notifications, apns-php

I've wrote an Server which sends the Notifications to APNS. It's my first time that i use APNS. When i send a Message the Payload which is shown on iPhone is like this:

`{aps: {alert: "Hello"}, alert:"Hello"}`

Is it correct that the alert is there twice?

Comment: Please post your code how do you prepare pay load ?

Answer (score 1):

The alert should not be placed outside the `aps` tag:

```
{
    "aps" : { "alert" : "Message received from Bob" }
}
```

All keys outside `aps` will be private/custom payload items. Also be aware that the push notification can not exceed 256 bytes: [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html)

Comment: I asked wrong. That's what i send but when i output the payload in the recieving app the alert is appended again like in the example in my question. Is this behaviour correct?

Comment: Not sure, never checked that before, but if you sent just the `aps` to Apple and it return the alert outside of the `aps` then it must be something that apple does. Just make sure that you sent the push notification in the correct way.